# How to call Python script from specific cells in a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a Python script to interact with a database and give some result. I create a new sheet in a workbook and save this result.

I have a workbook and I want to call this script from all the cells in a particular row in the active sheet of the workbook using the cell value as an argument to the script.

I came to know the following things
1) Create a VBA macro and call a script from the macro
2) Insert the macro in the sheet

I have zero knowledge about VBA and was not able to find good resources for it.

Can my problem can be solved using Python itself?

Can I call a Python script from some cells in a workbook using cell values as an argument to the script?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. The answer is yes. There are several libraries for it. Look into `openpyxl`, `win32com`: also called `pywin32`, and `pandas`

Of these 3,
`openpyxl` is the easiest to use but might not contain the full functionality of Excel VBA.
`win32com` is the closest to VBA and most function calls are the same right down to the way arguments are passed into them.
`pandas` is the right choice if you're crunching a lot of numbers and mainly using the spreadsheet files as data storage.

EDIT:

Screenshot of Excel UI with Command Button:

[image: Excel UI for Command Button]

VBA Code:

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArguments()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Config") 'Have a sheet named "Config"

    'The values here are for passing in the args to a python script that runs as an .exe file
    strProgramName = Trim(ws.Range("B4").Value) '.exe filepath
    strPdfLoc = Trim(ws.Range("B5").Value) 'file being acted on
    strPdfSave = Trim(ws.Range("B6").Value) 'file being created
    strPdfPass = Trim(ws.Range("B7").Value) 'additional argument
    'string concatenation
    strArgument = strPdfLoc & " " & strPdfSave & " " & strPdfPass

    'Checking the cmd line to be passed into the Shell as args for the .exe
    Debug.Print """" & strProgramName & """ " & strArgument & """"
    'How VBA calls the cmd to run
    'Note that """" actually prints one " because " is an escape char and also a string quote in VBA
    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ " & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

The above code showcases how you can create a macro to run an .exe and pass in arguments.
As for **trigger on cell selection**, use the example showcased in this [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4354-excel-click-on-cell-to-run-macro.html).

In order to create an `.exe` file, use `pip3 install pyinstaller` and `cd` your way to the folder containing the `.py` script, then run `pyinstaller --onefile yourscript.py`

Comment: I have done most of the automation work like updating spreadsheet,plotting graph based on updated spreadsheet etc using openpyxl.It would be good if you can point me some of the example of openpyxl . Most of the resources on the internet is guiding how to use openpyxl with excel but none of them tell how to call a python script using openpyxl from a spreadsheet-@ycx

Comment: @rikki Am I correct in saying that you wish for your user to press a button in Excel, and that button will run a python script?

Comment: Yes this is what I want.Also the button will be the cell and there will be a value of that cell which i have used in my script. So it should be  like when a cell is clicked the value of the cell is passed to script as script will be using it and the script will then run -@ycx

Comment: @rikki I have done something similar before, I'll give an updated answer soon. Edit: its on my other computer, will access it once I get home

Comment: It would be really a great help.Thanks-@ycx

Comment: @rikki  Hey, I'm kinda busy at the moment but I've included some of my previous example code that can be converted to what you require. The VBA code showcases what you require, I will include in an example of cell selection trigger soon, but you can reference the link here if you wish to explore it yourself: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4354-excel-click-on-cell-to-run-macro.html

Comment: yeah I will see it but do include your example when you get time. Thanks-@ycx